# Screenshots made on an iPhone XR are not accepted for 6.5 inch screenshots on App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-xr

I just bought a new iPhone XR so I could make the screenshots for my App Store app. Starting March 27th 2019, [you need to provide 6.5" (new phone models) screenshots:](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925)

[image: Screenshot Specifications for App Store]

However, App Store Connect is not accepting my screenshots made with this device. After further research, I found out that iPhone XR is actually 6.1":

[image: iPhone XR specifications]

I am not from the iOS world (I mainly work with Google and Android), so I am wondering if I am missing something, or are the docs wrong?

Comment: why don't you get the screenshots from the simulator ?

Comment: I don't own any apple hardware except this phone that I have now bought specifically to make screenshots.

Comment: @PrimožKralj how are you writing code, building and testing without any apple hardware?

Comment: Hm it is weird that the Apple page seems to have the wrong screen size for the iPhone XR… https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd1093d90d does not mention the XR. Looks like a mistake; I just sent an email to Apple developer support.

Comment: @PrimožKralj The iPhone XR and iPhone XS Max are the same logical size: 414x896. Just scale your iPhone XR screen shot to have the desired number of pixels.

Comment: The link lists the iPhone XR under 6.5"; the device is 6.1". Regardless of anything else, that's confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iPhone XR and iPhone XS Max *are* the same size: 414x896. The reason your screen shot is coming out the wrong size is that the iPhone XR is double resolution, where as the iPhone XS Max is triple resolution. But that's not a problem. If your screen shot is coming out as 828x1792, just run it through any basic image-munging app, such as Preview, and change the size to 150% of its current size:

```
 828 * 1.5 = 1242 
1792 * 1.5 = 2688
```

That gives you the required size, 1242x2688.

(Note, however, that you do not need *any* device merely in order to generate a screen shot acceptable to the App Store. Screen shots from the various Xcode Simulators will do just fine. Even an app that has functionality that doesn't quite work on the Simulator can be tweaked to generate its normal interface so that you can take the screen shot. I have nine apps currently on the App Store, each with an accepted set of screen shots, and *not one* of those screen shots was taken on a device.)

Comment: @user924 It’s not about this question. A simple search turns up this and lots of other duplicates instantly. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Screenshot+iPhone+XR Searching before asking is always good.

Answer (score 3):

The table is slightly misleading, the inclusion of the iPhone XR in that list actually means that it will **show the iPhone XS Max screenshots** if you visit the App Store listing of your app from an iPhone XR.

What is *actually* relevant when uploading a "6.5 inch" screenshot is the required size of the image, which is 1242x2688 or 2688x1242 pixels. The screenshots made on an iPhone XR are 828x1792 pixels in size [(source: iosres.com)](http://iosres.com/), that's why your screenshots got rejected.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. Your own link tells you the right answer: the iPhone XR and iPhone XS Max are the same logical size: 414x896. It's easy to munge an iPhone XR screen shot to have the desired number of pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Although iPhone XR and XS Max screens has the same size in terms of POINTS, they are not the same in terms of PIXELS (and inches).

```
XR:     6.1in, 828x1792 @2x
XS Max: 6.5in, 1242x2688 @3x  <--- you want this one.
```

There is confusion for required size because the spec says to use 6.5in screen for both XR and XS Max, implying they're both the same size.

Just use the XS Max simulator to take screenshots and you should be good.  I tried it just now, got the needed size.

Comment: Agree. Just had the same issue. But, using the iPhone XS Max simulator instead with the Window > Pixel Accurate size and taking a screenshot with File > New screen shot worked perfectly. 1242 × 2688 pixels